# Using CSS or JavaScript to limit the page size or limit positioning to prevent overlapping

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to add a footer to a page, but I don't want the footer to overlap the text if the user makes the page too small. How do I prevent this from happening without making a large table or a bunch of returns? The footer code is located in an included page. Perhaps there might be a way to chose when scrolling turns on or a minimum from the top CSS attribute.

I thought I explained it well enough, here's some more explanation:

On the page with the footer, there's a tag `include('footer.php')`.

In footer.php, there's a section of text aligned at the bottom, with something like,

```
<div style="position: fixed; bottom: 10px">Footer Text</div>
```

If the user makes the window too small, the text will overlap everything else. I'd rather it stay at the bottom and a scroll bar appear.

Comment: You should post code, no one can know why your footer would overlap your text without seeing your code.

Comment: Yes, code would be helpful. Have you used GitHub's [gists](gist.github.com) or jsFiddle before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not clear, but you might be looking for a [responsive layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design). This allows you to use a different set of CSS rules when the viewport's dimensions fall below a certain "breakpoint".

The specific technique is known as [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/). You might use it to hide the footer when the viewport gets too short, as follows:

```
@media screen and (max-height:700px) {
  footer { display: none; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're looking for something like a [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/), then?

Comment: Maybe, but you don't really know if this is a solution, because the problem has not yet been identified.

Comment: based on the question (and the limited information) This seems to be as good an answer as any.